# Do Beta Israel eat kitniot?

Tags: passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, ethiopian-beta-israel

Do Beta Israel eat kitniot during Pesach? More broadly do they have unique a mesorah for Pesach kashrus?

Comment: I am not (personally) aware of any evidence that they have any meaningful massoret on anything. In many ways they closely resembled their gentile neighbors.

Comment: the kitniyot ban is a relatively recent ashkenazi innovation. If they had any meaningful massoret, it would (presumably) not include the kiyniyot ban. Unless one claims that they are actually Ashkenazi, which sounds less likely than the Babylonian and Khazari origin theories of the Ashkenazim combined.

Comment: What is Beta Israel?

Comment: @DanF, Google? Wikipedia?

Comment: I imagined it was possible they arrived at the practice regarding kitniot the same way Ashkenazim did without being Ashkenazi ;)

Comment: @mevaqesh it's hard to imagine that they have NO masorot whatsoever even if one isn't personally familiar with any. They're calendar is unique to them?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull `it's hard to imagine that they have NO masorot whatsoever` I said `any evidence that they have any meaningful massoret on anything`.

Comment: @mevaqesh What constitutes  meaningful massoret?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull It is admittedly a bit of a circular term. I meant a tradition that is very old: like 1000 years (+).